# Windowsプロセスアクティブ化サービス（WAS）が開始できません。

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis

IISのアプリケーションプールを開始すると
「アプリケーションプールを開始するにためにはWindowsプロセスアクティブ化サービス（WAS）が実行中である必要があります」
と表示されたので以下のコマンドでWASを開始しましたがエラーが発生しました。

```
net start was
```

エラー内容

```
Windows プロセス アクティブ化サービス サービスを開始します.
Windows プロセス アクティブ化サービス サービスを開始できませんでした。

システム エラーが発生しました。

システム エラー 80 が発生しました。

ファイルがあります。
```

エラー内容を確認するためにイベントビューワーで確認したのですが、いまのところ原因がわかりません。現在、調査中なので分かり次第、ここに記載しますが詳しい方がいましたらご教授ください。以下にエラーの詳細を記載しておきます。

```
ログの名前:         System
ソース:           Microsoft-Windows-WAS
日付:            2018/01/29 21:58:34
イベント ID:       5005
タスクのカテゴリ:      なし
レベル:           エラー
キーワード:         クラシック
ユーザー:          N/A
コンピューター:       〇〇-PC
説明:
エラーが発生したため、Windows プロセス アクティブ化サービス (WAS) を停止します。データ フィールドにはエラー番号が含まれています。
イベント XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WAS" Guid="{524B5D04-133C-4A62-8362-64E8EDB9CE40}" EventSourceName="WAS" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">5005</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-01-29T12:58:34.245081100Z" />
    <EventRecordID>3557</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>〇〇-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Binary>50000780</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: 同じような問題を見つけました
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/2e3d3d50-884a-4e07-b2c2-577e532d1efd/was-windows-activation-service-failure-has-knocked-out-w3svc-etc?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: さっそくの投稿ありがとうございます！こちらのリンクを確認して試してみたのですが、解決できませんでした。System error 183 has occurred.
Cannot create a file when that file already exists.とエラー内容が違うので、引き続きこちらでも調査してみます。なにかわかりましたらご教授頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 調べたところ、テンポラリのファイルサイズが「65535」を超えた場合に発生するエラーのようです。今、確認できる環境でないので実施後共有します。

Comment: テンポラリファイルを削除してためしてもダメでした。。